# Get Type of Parameter from Generic Delegate functions

Tags: c#, generics, types, delegates, type-conversion

I have a list of Generic Delegates in a Dictionary, see below for the delegate stub.

```
public delegate TType Condition<T, TType>(T obj);
```

I have an object that I get from another dictionary. I need to cast the object to the correct type for the delegate. The cond is the current delegate function that was defined in another dll. Any suggestions or maybe another possible way to go about it? Thanks!

```
foreach (var cond in _conditionDict[key])
            {
                try
                {
                    Object obj = board[key] ;

                    Type objectType = obj.GetType();


                    if (objectType == condType)// need to find the condition type
                    {
                        Convert.ChangeType(obj, condType);//need to get condition typpe

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the type "T" from an instance of you delegate, use this call:

```
obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
```